# Email code is selecting only first row in DataSet to send email

Tags: c#, .net, email

When I'm trying to email the result that i have got those from the database.. 
then only first row is getting selected. I have put a break point and found out that I'm getting multiple values in my `dsresult` but when appending `dsresult` to the email then email is selecting only the first result.

I guess i should not use the `dsresult`. But any other which is gives me all the values in one row or which appends all the calues to the email body.

Here is the code...

```
        BAdmin objBAdmin = new BAdmin();
        BEAdmin objBEAdmin = new BEAdmin();

        BAdmin objSpAdmin = new BAdmin();
        objSpAdmin.BGetInvalidCourses(objBEAdmin);

        string invalid = objBEAdmin.DsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CourseId"].ToString();
        MailMessage email = new MailMessage();

        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();


         email = new MailMessage("email@abc.com", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email_To"]);
        email.Subject = "Invalid Courses ";
        email.CC.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FYIEmail_CC_Dataload"]);
        email.Body = "Test message: please ignore." + invalid;
        body.Append(@"<tr><td>Hi,<br/><br/> Please find the missing courses </p></td></tr>");
        body.Append("</table>");
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("pod51041.outlook.com", 587);
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]);
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(email);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works.
You forgot to add email.body.tostring();

```
        BAdmin objBAdmin = new BAdmin();
        BEAdmin objBEAdmin = new BEAdmin();

        BAdmin objSpAdmin = new BAdmin();
        objSpAdmin.BGetInvalidCourses(objBEAdmin);

     string invalid = objBEAdmin.DsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CourseId"].ToString();
        MailMessage email = new MailMessage();

        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();


         email = new MailMessage("abc@abc.com", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FYIEmail_To_Dataload"]);
        email.Subject = "Invalid Courses ";
        email.CC.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FYIEmail_CC_Dataload"]);
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in objBEAdmin.DsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            body.Append("please ignore." + dr["CourseId"].ToString());
        }
        body.Append(@"<tr><td>Hi,<br/><br/> Please find the missing courses </p></td></tr>");
        body.Append("</table>");
        email.Body = body.ToString();
        email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("pod51041.outlook.com", 587);
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]);
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(email);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line

`string invalid = objBEAdmin.DsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CourseId"].ToString();`

only the first row of the result table seems to be read. You should use something like

```
string invalid = String.Empty;
foreach ( DataRow iRow in abjBEAdmin.DsResult.Tables[0].Rows )
  invalid += iRow["CourseId"].ToString();
```

to append the `CourseId` column of each row to the string `invalid`.

Comment: Error 99 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataTable' because 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' G:\Canvas mailing test\CanvasDataload\Program.cs 1056 13 CanvasDataload

Comment: I was mistaken; you have to enumerate the `Rows` property. Please see the updated code.

Comment: Yes, its appending now.. i have seen that the text is also appending but when i get to the result im not getting any subject in the mail... im just getting a blank mail. though its appending in the for loop.

Comment: To my understanding, you are also filling a `StringBuilder` `body` which is never read from. Please show the code as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have written

```
string invalid = objBEAdmin.DsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CourseId"].ToString();
```

So it always select the first row of the `DsResult` .
If you need to send all the invalid Courses in the mail you should have a loop.

I've change the code...

```
email = new MailMessage("email@abc.com", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email_To"]);
email.Subject = "Invalid Courses ";
email.CC.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FYIEmail_CC_Dataload"]);

email.Body = "Test message:";
foreach(Datarow dr in objBEAdmin.DsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
{
body.Append("please ignore." + dr["CourseId"].ToString());
}

body.Append(@"<tr><td>Hi,<br/><br/> Please find the missing courses </p></td></tr>");
body.Append("</table>");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("pod51041.outlook.com", 587);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]);
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(email);
```

Comment: Error 99 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataTable' because 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' G:\Canvas mailing test\CanvasDataload\Program.cs 1056 13 CanvasDataload

Comment: Sorry I've edited the code..
Changed the line 
`foreach(Datarow dr in objBEAdmin.DsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
{
body.Append("please ignore." + dr["CourseId"].ToString());
}`

Comment: Yes, its appending now.. i have seen that the text is also appending but when i get to the result im not getting any subject in the mail... im just getting a blank mail. though its appending in the for loop.

Comment: I think there are some missing html tags in my code.Try to resolve that missing tags by appending them.
Debug and see what you get finally for your body message.